# How do I close the splash screen in an eclipse RCP application?

Tags: eclipse, splash-screen, rcp

In an eclipse RCP application, a `splash.bmp` is used as the splash screen. It closes after about 5-6 minutes of the application being run. I want it to close as soon as some UI displays. I tried using `Platform.endSplash()` and also `applicationRunning()` of the application context just before `PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(display, new ApplicationWorkbenchAdvisor())`.

It fails to close the splash screen.

Any suggestions would be helpful. It would also be okay if I could close the splash screen after about 10 -15 seconds.

```
public Object start(IApplicationContext arg0) throws Exception {
        Display display = PlatformUI.createDisplay();
        int returnCode = 0;
        try {

            //arg0.applicationRunning();
            Platform.endSplash();
            returnCode = PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(display,
                    new ApplicationWorkbenchAdvisor());

            if (returnCode == PlatformUI.RETURN_RESTART) {
                return PlatformUI.RETURN_RESTART;
            }

        return PlatformUI.RETURN_OK;
        } finally {
           //some other code here.
            display.dispose();
        }
}
```

Comment: I've never encountered this before.  In all my RCP applications, the splash.bmp closes as soon as the application starts.  What version of Eclipse are you using?

Comment: Version: Indigo Service Release 2
Build id: 20120216-1857

Answer (score 0):

I would expect the splash screen to close when everything is initialized, not after a set amount of seconds. Otherwise you don't even need one.

According to [this thread](http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t114238.html), you should make sure to call the `Platform.endSplash()` method in the right context, meaning the method `start(IApplicationContext context)`

If you already do this, please provide some code to help us understand your problem

Answer (score 0):

The closing of a splash screen is handled by the created `StartupMonitor` in `Workbench`.

After the workbench part is created (as you say, "as soon as some UI displays"), it will be cycling through all registered startup services. The fact that you have your workbench visible and have to wait ~5-6 minutes (or seconds) for your splash screen to close means you have another startup monitor preventing your desired UI transition.